# CakePHP hasOne association returns array of empty fields for non-existant record

Tags: mysql, cakephp, model-associations, cakephp-2.5

Have User and UserProfile models. User model has hasOne association with UserProfile. UserProfile mysql table is empty. When I do $this->User->find('all', array('contain' => array('UserProfile'))) instead of an empty UserProfile array, as you would expect, I get an array populated with empty fields that correspond to schema:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [firstname] => Joe
                    [surname] => Bloggs
                    [email] => katie.barnes@scotlandsdna.com
                    [password] => $2a$10$re4r7AXWQcXgkKcabUqmtO6j.7p2bA1t2SLeG93eVsiDPBgGaeXRS
                    [enabled] => 1
                    [user_group_id] => 1
                    [created] => 2014-06-26 15:01:38
                    [modified] => 2014-06-26 15:01:38
                )

            [UserProfile] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 
                    [job_title] => 
                    [user_id] => 
                    [enabled] => 
                    [created] => 
                    [modified] => 
                )

        )
```

Anyone seen this and know how to fix it?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct behavior because the `hasOne` association is *not optional*. If you want to make it optional, then change it to a `hasMany` and only ever create one record.

Cake is performing a `LEFT JOIN` from `User` to `UserProfile` and the query result produced `NULL` values for the missing record. This is the same result you would get if you executed the SQL in an editor outside of Cake.